# Automate browserstack: Keyboard is not open on iphone web safari

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, appium-android, appium-ios, browserstack

I am able to launch URL on safari browser using Appium and

```
"@wdio/browserstack-service"
```

but the keyboard is not opening, and the script is not able to enter text in the input field. It works fine on physical device( Both Android and iPhone), it also works fine on browserstack Android chrome browser. This issue is only with iPhone safari. Please can somebody help?

I tried with different capabilities.

```
realMobile: true,
```

but nothing seems to help

Answer (score -1):

**Hello, Please find your answer.** There is no separate method to open keyboard - it is only opened when an element with input focus is activated. Regarding how you activate it - try to perform the click in native context.

Comment: The same script is running fine on local iOS simulator